# Show unicode HTML entities messing up my style

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

So, this morning, for fun, I grabbed the file of unicode characters over at http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.2.0/ucd/NamesList.txt and wrote a little tiny PHP script that will output that to the screen. It takes a couple seconds to load the literally thousands of characters and render the HTML.

I tried to make a very simple grid, using inline-block divs with overflow hidden. But when I view the page in Chrome some of the boxes are shifted down or up from the rest on it's row. But only sometimes.

http://shawnsworld.ca/chars/fullunicode.php

The CSS code: http://shawnsworld.ca/chars/style.css

Any idea why Chrome would render the boxes so they are NOT in a straight row?

Comment: I can't say why it would happen like that in Chrome, but it doesn't seem to happen in Firefox. Perhaps Chrome associates the offset that some diacritic characters imply with the box itself rather than the text inside the box? That wouldn't really make sense, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chrome, `div.character` has a default `vertical-align` of `baseline`.

Try removing `height:100px;` from `div.character` in your CSS. You'll see that all the boxes are sitting on the baseline of each row.

As Huangism says, changing the `vertical-align` to `top` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding vertical-align to your divs

```css
div.characters {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something to compare:
http://www.unicodeblocks.com/block/Dingbats

Is this what you looking for? If yes I can give you some advice.

...other thing, there are lots of errors, in example:

```
<div class="character">
<span class="entity">&#x@@;</span><br>
<span class="unicodeNumber">@@ </span><br>
<span class="name">07C0</span>
</div>
```

just skip any line starting with @